# AWS s3 private bucket creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

How would you create a private s3 bucket from the aws cli?

My command is

```
aws s3api create-bucket --bucket my-bucket --region eu-west-2 --create-bucket-configuration LocationConstraint=eu-west-2 --acl private
```

But on bucket creation, there's public read enabled.
What I expect to see under Access is

**Bucket and objects not public**

not **Objects can be public**

Answer (score 3):

All Amazon S3 buckets are **private by default**.

Content is not accessible unless the is permitted with a Bucket Policy or an Object ACL.

Buckets are not publicly readable by default.

Answer (score 2):

You can block public access by using the [`aws s3api put-public-access-block`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-public-access-block.html) command after creating the S3 bucket.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I needed

Comment: It seems this has to be `aws s3api ...` instead of `aws s3 ...`.